# Class not found with mvn exec:java during runtime

Tags: java, maven, maven-exec-plugin

I am trying to use the command mvn exec:java unsuccessfully.

I configure my pom.xml with the mainClass parameter and add the different dependencies.

I use version 3.0.0 of exec-maven-plugin.

It runs but I get an execption 'java.lang.NullPointerException' during the runtime that say that package **'package1' doesnt contain 'class1.class'**.

It works perfecally in Eclipse and when I package my project.

I have the same package use, one in my project and other one in a jar added as dependency in my pom.xml. I suppose that during the runtime, the runtime goes in the wrong package search the class.

Have you already had this problem and do you know how to solve it ?

I try this but unsuccessfully: [Maven exec:java run executable plugin dependency jar results in NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409624/maven-execjava-run-executable-plugin-dependency-jar-results-in-npe)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please add the POM, the command you ran and the output.